# VideoView playing .m3u8 in Fragment won't play in Nexus 7. Plays fine in HTC1 M8

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-videoview

My VideoView Fragment does not play my .m3u8 type video while I am running it in the Nexus 7 (Android 4.4.2), with the "Can't play this video" error popping up. This is confusing because I am using the same code on my HTC1 M8 (4.4.4) and it runs just fine.

Here is my code for the fragment:

```
public class VideoFragment extends Fragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_fragment, container, false);
    VideoView vidView = (VideoView)view.findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
    String vidAddress1 = "http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/nasatv/NTV-Public-IPS.m3u8";
    Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress1);
    vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
    MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(getActivity()); /* Video controls */
    vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView);
    vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);
    vidView.start();
    return view; }
}
```

Just to be clear, the fragments themselves show up fine, it is just the video that is not playing.

Is there any reason why this would not work on the Nexus 7?

Thank you for your help, it is very much appreciated.

Edit: added video type

Edit 2: Just to make sure it was not the video itself I tested each video listed here with my code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104301/hls-streaming-video-url-need-for-testing/13265943#13265943

Each one had the same issue, where it played on my HTC1 M8 but not on my Nexus 7.

Answer (score 0):

So I updated the Nexus to Android 4.4.3 and downloaded a new upgrade to Android Studio as well. Now my code runs just fine.

Lesson learned: make sure devices are up to date.